# Why is Google Closure Compiler failing on my ES6 object which extends Date()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-closure-compiler

**Please note:** this question relates to the use of Google's Closure Compiler. It's not directly about ES6, since that part is working.

I've written a class in ES6 which extends the native Date object. It's a large class, but this is a simplified version:

```
   class Dative extends Date {

       constructor (dateData) {
           super();
           super.setTime(Date.parse(dateData));
       }


       addMilliseconds (ms) {
           super.setTime(super.getTime() + ms);
       }

   }
```

The code above works fine in Chrome and Firefox. However, when I pass it through Closure Compiler, it throws errors:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Method Date.prototype.setTime called on
> incompatible receiver [object Object]
> ```

**Update:** calling native Date methods also fails in the compiled version but works fine uncompiled, with a message saying this is not a Date object.

What I don't understand is why code that works in its original form breaks when it's been compiled.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a compiler bug?

I'm using the latest version of compiler.jar. For reference, this is what closure compiler produces:

```
var $jscomp = {
    scope: {},
    inherits: function(a, b) {
        function d() {}
        d.prototype = b.prototype;
        a.prototype = new d;
        a.prototype.constructor = a;
        for (var c in b)
            if (Object.defineProperties) {
                var e = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(b, c);
                e && Object.defineProperty(a, c, e)
            } else
                a[c] = b[c]
    }
}
  , Dative = function(a) {
    Date.call(this);
    Date.prototype.setTime.call(this, Date.parse(a))
};

$jscomp.inherits(Dative, Date);
Dative.UTC = Date.UTC;
Dative.parse = Date.parse;
Dative.now = Date.now;
Dative.prototype.addMilliseconds = function(a) {
    Date.prototype.setTime.call(this, Date.prototype.getTime.call(this) + a)
};
//# sourceMappingURL=./DativeShort.map
```

Comment: Raised as a bug: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/1953

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` is not subclassable in ES5. So what you want is not possible in ES5 environments in the first place.

The transpiled code cannot work in ES6 environments either. From the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-constructor)

> The Date constructor is designed to be subclassable. It may be used as the value of an extends clause of a class definition. Subclass constructors that intend to inherit the specified Date behaviour must include a super call to the Date constructor to create and initialize the subclass instance with a [[DateValue]] internal slot.

Without calling `super` it won't work. `Date.call(this);` doesn't do the trick. Basically, if you transpile code to ES5, subclassing built-in types is a no-go.

So no, it's not a problem of Google Closure.

Comment: I believe this is correct. I verified that Babel's transpilation of this also is non-functional.

Comment: Thanks, useful information. I was hoping Closure would know how to replicate ES6 behaviour in ES5 :(