# Override constructor in Date subclass

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a new `Date` descendant class and override the constructor:

```
export class MyDate extends Date {
  constructor(str: string) {
    super(str);
  }
}
```

Now, if I create a `MyDate` object, it doesn't work :

```
var myDate = new MyDate("2016-10-20T12:30:00+0200");
console.log(myDate.toDateString()); // it crashes, myDate is incorrect
```

I get `TypeError: Method Date.prototype.toDateString called on incompatible receiver [object Object]`.

How can I override the `Date` constructor? Is it possible?

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis in your `MyDate` declaration. Is that there in your original code? You'll also need to state exactly what happens when you try to log. What does "it crashes" mean?

Comment: You are right, the class is :<br/>

`class MyDate extends Date {`<br/>
`  constructor(str: string) {`
`    super(str);`
`  }`
`}`

and the error is :

`TypeError: Method Date.prototype.toDateString called on incompatible receiver [object Object]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this question and the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954597/why-is-google-closure-compiler-failing-on-my-es6-object-which-extends-date/38971189#38971189), this happens because subclassing `Date` is not allowed in ES5. The following ES6 code works in Chrome because Chrome natively supports ES6 classes (it's exactly the same as your code, except I removed type annotations):

```js
class MyDate extends Date {
  constructor(str) {
    super(str);
  }
}

var myDate = new MyDate("2016-10-20T12:30:00+0200");
console.log(myDate.toDateString());
```

If you only need this to work in environments that natively support ES6 classes, change TypeScript's [`--target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) compiler option to `'es6'`. Otherwise, you will need to do something else.

One workaround might be to define `MyDate` so that it has a `Date` as a member variable. For example:

```
class MyDate {

  private date: Date;

  constructor(str: string) {
    this.date = new Date(str);
  }

  toDateString(): string {
    return this.date.toDateString();
  }
}
```