# Is it possible to extend Date by overloading the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

My data contains dates provided in various formats, a lot of which are not recognised by Typescript. I created a "safeDateParse" function which provides extended conversions and overloaded the Date.parse() method.

```
/** My overload */
Date.parse = function parse(dateAsString: string)  {
    return safeDateParse(dateAsString).valueOf();
};
```

This works when I create a Date object using the following syntax.

```
const lastUsedDate = new Date(Date.parse(lastUsed));
```

I would also like to overload the constructor in order to use the following syntax.

```
let newDate = new Date(dateString);
```

My best effort so far

```
function Date(dateAsString: string): Date {
        return safeDateParse(dateAsString);
}
```

This does not work. It replaces the Date class, not extending it. I feel it should have some form of "super" or "parent" call within it that provides the rest of the Date object.

Is it possible to override the constructor, and if so, what is the syntax?

Comment: It is always risky to overload built in objects like Date. It's probably better to simply have that parse function as a static function and use it that way; `let newDate = new Date(safeDateParse(dateString))`. That way, there's no confusion when someone else reads your code.

Comment: I agree but I am looking at the problem of having to update existing code and an ongoing problem of getting other programmers to use a non-standard version of a basic command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can overwrite Date constructor the usual way:

```
window.Date = function (orig) {
  return function (...params) {
    // Do some custom stuff here
    return new orig(...params)
  }
}(Date)
```

Comment: "Property 'Date' does not exist on type 'Window'"  or if I remove window to have Date = function....   I get "Cannot assign to 'Date' because it is a constant or a read-only property.  "

Answer (score 0):

Use this code as a starting point :

```
Date.parse = function parse(dateAsString: string) {
    console.log('Overrided parse :)');
    return safeDateParse(dateAsString).valueOf();
};  

class MyDate extends Date {
    constructor(dateAsString: string) {
        console.log('extended Date');
        const d = Date.parse(dateAsString);
        super(d);
    }
}

window['Date'] = MyDate;

new Date();
// logs :
// extended Date
// Overrided parse :)
```

Comment: It looked hopeful, but I hit upon problems as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415970/override-constructor-in-date-subclass   Also hit upon constructor overloading problems i.e. const d = new Date(); stopped working as this was no longer defined.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I never succeeded in overloading the constructor. I discovered that the parameter uses DateConstructor to handle the various overloadings. My solution, if possible, would have to handle these overloads. In the end, I reluctantly opted for the solution below and having to educate the other programmers to use my Utility.safeDate() rather than new Date()

```
public static safeDate(dateAsString: string): Date {
    return new Date(safeDateParse(dateAsString));
}
```

and an example call.

```
const dateObject = Utility.safeDate('șapte mai 1983')
```